# Windsor, EF and Transaction-per-Request

Tags: entity-framework, castle-windsor

So I'm trying to implement Transaction per request with Castle Windsor with Tasks. I have theese 2 interfaces

```
public interface IRunOnEachRequest
    {
        void Execute();
    }

    public interface IRunAfterEachRequest
    {
        void Execute();
    }
```

In global.asax, Application_BeginRequest and Application_EndRequest take care of running all Execute methods from classes, that implement theese interfaces, like this:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var taskRunner = container.Resolve<RunOnEachRequestTaskRunner>();
      taskRunner.RunAll();
}

protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var taskRunner = container.Resolve<RunAfterEachRequestTaskRunner>();
     taskRunner.RunAll();
}
```

TaskRunners take dependency of IEnumerable tasks

```
public RunOnEachRequestTaskRunner(IEnumerable<IRunOnEachRequest> tasks)
        {
            _tasks = tasks;
        }
```

Because of this, I have added Windsor Subdependency Resolver, so it can take IEnumerable<> as dependency:

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
```

TransactionManager implements both interfaces and defines functions for each of them:

```
public class TransactionManager : IRunOnEachRequest, IRunAfterEachRequest
    {
        private MainDbContext _context;

        public TransactionManager(MainDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        void IRunOnEachRequest.Execute()
        {

        }

        void IRunAfterEachRequest.Execute()
        {

        }
    }
```

**So here is the problem:** After opening application, I get this error:

```
Can't create component 'Onion1stTry.Tasks.RunAfterEachRequestTaskRunner' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'Onion1stTry.Tasks.RunAfterEachRequestTaskRunner' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Onion1stTry.Tasks.IRunAfterEachRequest, Onion1stTry, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.
```

Seems, that there is problem with TransactionManager. If I implement only one Execute methods, everything is ok, but when there are 2 of them (one for each interfaces) I get this error.

**EDIT1: Added IRunOnEachRequest/IRunAfterEachRequest registration.**

```
container.Register(
                Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn<IRunOnEachRequest>()
                .WithService.FromInterface()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(
               Classes.FromThisAssembly()
               .BasedOn<IRunAfterEachRequest>()
               .WithService.FromInterface()
               .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

Comment: have you registered IRunOnEachRequest/IRunAfterEachRequest and their implementations?

Comment: Yes, I have. Check out edited code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else finds this useful, here is answer to my own question:

First problem was registering interfaces. Instead of this:

```
.WithService.FromInterface()
```

I should have used this:

```
.WithService.AllInterfaces()
```

Second, Application_EndRequest event. After fixing first problem, I got another one -

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Scope cache was already disposed. This is most likely a bug in the calling code.'.
```

The solution was to call the same code from Application_ReleaseRequestState instead.